# JavaScript for Firefox Add-on/Extension: "failed to execute script: Error: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object"

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-developer-tools

I am looking forward to receive some help on this little but tedious problem of mine that seems I am not currently able to solve since a few weeks so far.

I am trying to develop a very easy/simple **Extension/Add-on for the Mozilla Firefox browser**.

My little project is to develop a simple extension-button that when clicked will *allow the user to run an easy automated script on the current open webpage/tab*. Basically, *the script will try to extract some specific data from the page and present it in a new popup window created at the moment*.

I am currently stuck and cannot achieve the desire result while getting the following error:

```
failed to execute script: Error: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object
```

*P.S.: I am not using or working with any webpage that contains <iframe> tags.*

The original script itself is a little bit elaborated but nothing complex.
Trying to isolate the problem and the error I have tried to simplify the whole project in order to reproduce locally.

### **To summarize and recap**:

- I am trying to create a simple/easy **extension**/Add-on for the Mozilla Firefox **web-browser** (and *later extend this to the Google Chrome browser also*);
- the **scope** of this extension is to be able to run *only on a specific domain and set of pages*.
- once the user load that specific page, if desired, the user can **click on the extension button** and this will *run the script*.
- **the script will** need to search and try to *extract specific parts of the content* of the current webpage *and present this information on a new popup window created on the fly* (here the user should need to know that needs to add permission for popup pages for this domain/website)
- when the user is done with this summarized version of the page will be able to close it like a normal browser window.

### How the folder/file **structure of my project** is currently designed:

```
/generic-folder/
    test-page.html
    /browser-extension/
        /icons/
            icon-48.png
            icon-96.png
        /scripts/
            script.js
        app.js
        manifest.json
```

### **Description and content of the project:**

- the file: `test-page.html` is a test webpage created for the purpose in order to test the behavior of the script/extension and to reproduce the behavior/error locally, the content of this file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body style="color: white; background-color: black;">
        <h1>TEST NEW PAGE</h1>
        <p id="paragraph">
            This is the content of the paragraph that needs to be extracted!
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

- the `icons` folder contain 2 icon files PNG format, 48 pixels and 96 pixels. (not relevant)
- the `scripts` folder contain the main JavaScript script of the extension `script.js`, here the content:

```
var body = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n";
var font = "font-size: 1.25rem; font-family: Courier New, Monospace; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;";
var id = "paragraph";

body += "<html><body style=\""+font+"\"><h1>TEST NEW PAGE</h1>\n";
body += "<p>\n";
body += document.getElementById(id).innerText;
body += "\n</p>\n";
body += "\n</body>\n</html>\n";

var newWin = window.open('','extractor','width=1024,height=750,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
newWin.document.write(body);
newWin.focus();

console.log("Message: '/scripts/script.js' has been executed!");
```

**Note**: if you open in *debugging-mode (SHIFT+CTRL+C)* the webpage `test-page.html` and manually run the above `script.js` it should work as wanted and you should see the desire behavior of the project.

- the file `app.js` contain the JavaScript for the extension:

```
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(async (tab) => {
  try {
    let results = await browser.tabs.executeScript({
      file: "/scripts/script.js"
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`failed to execute script: ${err}`);
  }
});
```

- the file `manifest.json` contains the MetaData for the extension as described on the *[Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) pages @ developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension)* and the content is: *(maybe I need to make a better version of this too...)*

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Page Extractor",
    "description": "Script for extracting specific data from a webpage.",
    "version": "1.0",

    "icons": {
         "48": "icons/icon-48.png",
         "96": "icons/icon-96.png"
    },

    "permissions": ["webRequest", "scripting", "activeTab", "tabs", "clipboardWrite"],

    "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["*://*/test-page.html*"],
      "js": ["/app.js"]
    }],

    "background":{
        "scripts":["/app.js"]
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
             "48": "icons/icon-48.png",
             "96": "icons/icon-96.png"
        },
    "default_title": "Execute Page Extractor!"
    }
}
```

**When testing the extension**: *(following the MDN instructions)*
  `Firefox -> about:debugging -> load temporary extension -> etc...`

I can see the the web-extension correctly loaded with the correct icon, but, after I open the `test-page.html` (or the desired webpage), and click on the extension button then nothing happens!

However, I can see in the `test-page.html` debugging/console that the script has been ran (due to some manual debugging message I've tried to place)... but **no** popup/new window is presented/created to the user.

Instead analyzing the "**Inspection**" debugging window of the extension I can see the following error message:

```
failed to execute script: Error: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object
```

I cannot find the correct work-around/solution and I hope that someone can help me out.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's a [bug in Firefox](https://bugzil.la/1508687). The workaround might be to run the code in the context of the page: newWin = wrappedJSObject.open(.....

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I have found my answer the same day I have created this post and, also as the user [`wOxxOm`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) suggested, this is a known Firefox [**bug**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1508687) [ *https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1508687* ].

At the moment I was able to isolate the problem (without avoiding a small "*console error message*") and make it work following the information found at this official page:
*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts*

*(page, which reports:)*

> In Firefox, part of the isolation between content scripts and page
> scripts is implemented using a feature called "Xray vision". When a
> script in a more-privileged scope accesses an object that's defined in
> a less-privileged scope it sees only the "native version" of the
> object. Any expando properties are invisible, and if any properties of
> the object have been redefined, it sees the original implementation,
> not the redefined version.

### Hence... Solution is:

to change this:

```
newWin.document.write(body);
```

into this:

```
newWin.wrappedJSObject.write(body);
XPCNativeWrapper(newWin);
```